# Handling collision with mail addresses in local (send-only) postfix and external mail provider

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, domain

I have a domain `foo.com` pointing to my server and have MX entries redirecting to an external (!) mail provider where I can send and receive mails via `mail@foo.com`. Since I am running some applications on my server that should send mail notifications I have installed postfix with the following changes to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

And the respective `/etc/postfix/generic` looks like this:

```
root@foo.com       no-reply@foo.com
@foo.com           no-reply@foo.com
```

Unfortunately it turns out that sending mails locally (either via `mail` or the applications connecting to the localhost) to my `mail@foo.com` will of course conflict with the local postfix installation that should not receive the mail and the mail should rather be forwarded to my externally hosted mail server from the provider.

How can I configure the server such that locally sent mails to `mail@foo.com` will in fact reach the external server?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that helped me achieve what I want and it's [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/630549/23607). Basically I had to change the `mydestination` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to be empty to prevent local delivery.

On top of that I changed my maps to exclude the second `@foo.com` line and replaced the `root` with the postfix username.